# How to wait current thread execution and execute another thread completedly

Tags: java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    public void run() {
         testFun1();
    }

     public void testFun1(){
          for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
              try {  
                  Thread.sleep(1000);
                      System.out.println("From testFun1() = "+i);
               } catch (Exception e) {
           }  

        }

      } 

    }

class Thread2 extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        testFun2();
    }

    public synchronized void testFun2() {
        try {
              for(int i=20;i<=25;i++){
               Thread.sleep(1000);  
               System.out.println("From testFun2() = "+i);           
        }
      }
    }
```

---

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       try{ 
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
        Thread2 thread1 = new Thread2();
        thread1.start();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        thread1.join();
        thread2.start();
     }catch(Exception e){
     }

   }
}
```

---

Required output:

```
From testFun1() 1
From testFun1() 2
From testFun1() 3
From testFun2() 20
From testFun2() 21
From testFun2() 22
From testFun2() 23
From testFun2() 24
From testFun2() 25
From testFun1() 4
From testFun1() 5
From testFun1() 6
From testFun1() 7
From testFun1() 8
From testFun1() 9
From testFun1() 10
```

But didn't get the above out put.

Comment: Can you adjust the formatting to remove the blank lines, pls ?

Comment: Your code as it is doen't compile (missing catch blocks, thread1 declared twice...). Please post a working example.

Comment: @NathanHughes Maybe they try to understand things.

Comment: What do you _really_ want? Do you want the output from thread1 and thread2 to be interspersed, or do you want thread2 to be run completely in the middle of thread1? When you say 'required output', I assume you don't mean _exactly_ that, since it is almost impossible to guarantee that kind of output without a lot more co-ordination.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `thread1.join()` will wait until `thread1` completes what it is doing. So your 2 threads will run one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class. It's class javadoc has an example of co-ordinating threads.

Answer (score 0):

Your output suggests what you actually have is

```
thread1.start();

Thread.sleep(3000);

thread2.start();

thread1.join();
```

If the last two line were the other way around thread1 would run to completion before thread2 started.

Comment: I think he's saying that he is NOT getting that output, but would like to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i came up with, [please comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/thread-pausing-resuming-implementation) any suggestions/improvements/bad practices.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1();
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2();

        try {
            thread1.start();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            synchronized (thread1) {
                thread1.waiting = true;
                thread2.start();
                thread2.join();
                thread1.waiting = false;
                thread1.notify();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO actually handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Class Thread1.java

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {
    boolean waiting = false;

    public void run() {
        testFun1();
    }

    public void testFun1() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (waiting) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //TODO Handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("From testFun1() = " + i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO Handle exception

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Thread2.java

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        testFun2();
    }

    public void testFun2() {
        try {
            for (int i = 20; i <= 25; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //catch
                }
                System.out.println("From testFun2() = " + i);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO do something
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java -Didea.launcher.port=7543 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\alt-rt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\alt-string.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\IdeaProjects\PracticeModule\target\classes;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain jmhp.core.App
From testFun1() = 1
From testFun1() = 2
From testFun1() = 3
From testFun1() = 4
From testFun1() = 5
From testFun2() = 20
From testFun2() = 21
From testFun2() = 22
From testFun2() = 23
From testFun2() = 24
From testFun2() = 25
From testFun1() = 6
From testFun1() = 7
From testFun1() = 8
From testFun1() = 9
```

Regards!

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, edit your original question. That would make it much more simple to comment.